What is the "lifted system of linear equations"?
I am reading this blog post, where it says

Here’s another variant of the same idea. Suppose we want to solve the linear system of equation $(D + uv^\top)x = b$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Then we can immediately write down the lifted system of linear equations
$$
\begin{equation*}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} -1 & v^\top \\ u & D \end{bmatrix}}_{:=M}\begin{bmatrix} y \\ x \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ b \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
$$

How is the "lifted system of linear equations" defined for linear systems $Ax = b$ in general, and what's the solution to the original problem in terms of the solution to the lifted system $\begin{bmatrix} y^* \\ x^* \end{bmatrix}$?

Once you’ve solved for $(x,y)$ you’ll have the $x$ of the original system. Think of $y$ as an auxiliary variable. I admit I’ve never heard the term lifted system before.

@Aruralreader Thanks! That is not obvious to see (at least for me). Can you point me to a reference/proof of this result?

I've heard of "lifting" as a general concept of representing an object in some sort of high dimensional space so this is a similar concept. A common setting where you see this term used is in optimal transport, where a metric on some space can be "lifted" to induce a metric on the space of probability measures over the same space

Suppose $x$ and $y$ satisfy the 'lifted system.' Expanding the system you see $v^T x = y$ and $uy + Dx = b$. Substituting $y$ from the former into the latter gives $uv^T x + Dx = b$, so $(uv^T + D)x = b$, which shows any such $x$ satisfies the initial system.

Thanks. This is certainly helpful, but I guess the "real" question is, how did someone come up with such a construction? Why is it useful to reformulate a linear system in this way? Does it have a name that I can look up in the literature? (I already tried "lifted system", but that doesn't match anything)
